# Need helping making a multi table query in access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access-2010

This is the SQL code I have at the moment, what can I do to fix it because when I try to run it it says `Type Mismatch in expression`

```
SELECT tblCustomers.CustomerID, tblCustomers.Lastname, tblCustomers.Firstname,      
       tblCustomers.AddressLine1, tblCustomers.Phone, tblOrders.OrderID, 
       tblOrders.CustomerID, tblOrders.NumberOfCDs, tblOrders.OrderDate,  
       tblOrders.PaymentType, tblOrders.AmountPaid, tblOrders.Discount, tblOrders.OrderSent
FROM tblCustomers 
INNER JOIN tblOrders ON tblCustomers.CustomerID = tblOrders.CustomerID;
```

P.S: I have just started to learn to use access so forgive my 'Noobyness' for lack of a better word.

Comment: Are the two `CustomerID` fields of the same data type?

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare apples to oranges.

Meaning, when you compare 2 things, they need to be of the samee type.

Here  `tblCustomers.CustomerID = tblOrders.CustomerID` you compare 2 things - make sure that they have the same type.

Read [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/i-get-a-message-about-type-mismatch-HP001122322.aspx) , get db schema for both table and compare `CustomerID` on both.