# Stuck on access query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ms-access-2013

I have a certain query I have to make, these are the specifications:

*Orders Ready to Send Out with Customer Address. These types of orders can be identified because the amount owing for the order will be less than or equal to 0 (if the amount still left to pay is less than zero, this means they have actually overpaid so the order can still be shipped out), and the order will not be marked as sent out (sent out is false). This query should list all of the customer's information, including name, address and phone, and all of the order information, The output should be sorted by city, and then by customer last name.*

This is the sql I have for the query:

```
SELECT tblCustomers.CustomerID, tblCustomers.Lastname, tblCustomers.Firstname,      
       tblCustomers.AddressLine1, tblCustomers.Phone, tblOrders.OrderID, 
       tblOrders.CustomerID, tblOrders.NumberOfCDs, tblOrders.OrderDate,  
       tblOrders.PaymentType, tblOrders.AmountPaid, tblOrders.Discount, tblOrders.OrderSent
FROM tblCustomers 
INNER JOIN tblOrders ON tblCustomers.CustomerID = tblOrders.CustomerID;
```

When I try to run the query it says "Type mismatch in expression" how can I fix this?

Comment: what varieity of sql is this?

Comment: You must give us table definitions to answer this, but a good guess is your column types for CustomerID differ in tblCustomers and tblOrders.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Need helping making a multi table query in access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24362572/need-helping-making-a-multi-table-query-in-access)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One likely explanation is that the datatype of the `CustomerID` column in tblCustomers is DIFFERENT from the datatype of `CustomerID` column in `tblOrders`.

There's insufficient information provided to diagnose any further.

Comment: Yeah the customerID in tblCustomers is autonumber and the other is short text, how should I fix this?

Comment: @user3766854: You can try tblCustomers.CustomerID = CLng(tblOrders.CustomerID)